# Translate 表面風光、內裏陰乾 in English

Tags: idioms

Translate 表面風光、內裏陰乾 in english.

Where is this ancient idiom coming from by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an idiom, but a typical [順口溜](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A0%86%E5%8F%A3%E6%BA%9C) (Jingle)

表面(on the surface)

風光(look good)* *short from 好風光(good scenery)- something look good in people's eyes)*

內裏(inside)

[陰乾](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/15331/)(slowly dry up in dry dark place)

It means 'someone seems well off in the public's eyes, but in reality, is flat broke.'

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend another.

In simplified Chinese, you can find a similar but different one

金玉其外，败絮其中

金玉其外, on the surface it is gold

败絮其中, but inside it is just rubbish

It's very impolite to describe a person in this way. That means this guy is actually an asshole but masked with a polite, friendly and gorgeous appearance.